# response.d in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and would like to understand what is the difference between response and response.d, i am using response.d in failure alerts.

i wanted to know in case of failure what alert(respose.d) would display in message box.

below is my code

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST", 
url:"Abc.aspx/Function1",
data: '{MonthDateID: ' + $('#<%=ddlMonth.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
dataType: "json",
success: Function2,
failure: function(response) { 
alert(response.d);}});
```

Please do let me know in case of any query

Comment: Your data isn't json, object properties have to be quoted and if its value is a string that needs to be quoted too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

response is the object always.
In order to to get your data you have to use response.d.

If you put only response in alert it will show you something like `[Object]` in the alert.

Suppose, response contains a message "Ajax call made successfully" then to see the message you have to use response.d ("d") property of response.

Comment: what response.d would return in case of failure ?